# Same xpath of webelement but sometimes doesn't work - scraping Amazon

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

I am practicing scraping amazon search results. As I got `asin` number for each item on the page, I created an item's Webelement through for loop using `asin`

**Edit** here is the webpage that I'am scraping [click here](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=wireless%20charger&qid=1630676207&ref=sr_pg_1)

```
for asin in product_asin:
    item_path = '//div[@data-asin="' + asin + '"]'
    item_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath(item_path)

    # find and add title 
    title = item_details.find_element_by_xpath('.//div//span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]')
    product_titles.append(title.text)
    

    # find and add a product link
    product_link = item_details.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="a-link-normal a-text-normal"]').get_attribute("href")
    product_links.append(product_link)
    
    # find prices
    whole_price = item_details.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="a-price-whole"]')
    fraction_price = item_details.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="a-price-fraction"]')
   

    if whole_price != [] and fraction_price != []:
        price = '.'.join([whole_price[0].text, fraction_price[0].text])
        product_prices.append(price)
    else:
        product_prices.append(0)
```

I've got a problem when getting **product's price.** As some products have prices but it cannot find the price (so they're replaced with 0).

> Website's search results which include price for "Yoo.."

[image: Search results with price]

> Data scraped - all elements work except price (But the last item has no price from the start)

[image]

Comment: Share that particular URL.

Comment: Put some `time.sleep()` and try.

Comment: I've added the link. I wonder where to put ```time.sleep()``` , before finding price or before all processes. @pmadhu

Comment: put `time.sleep()` atleast of 2 seconds one before `item_path` line and after `item_details` line.

Comment: I tried to do only for `//div[@data-asin='B079KZ49PJ']"`, sometimes it finds 2 elements with that `xpath` and sometimes its 4. And I get the price as `12.99`, without implicit wait, time.sleep and scrollingIntoView. Not sure why you are getting 0.

Comment: @pmadhu  I don't know as well why I got 0 for that ```B079KZ49PJ```. Last night I tried to record the data in sql instead and it has no missing value. Thank you very much for helping me examine the problem. Do you know why sometimes you got 2 elements why sometimes 4 even in the same product.